# Is it practical to use the "rude big hammer" approach to parallelize a MacOS/CoreAudio real-time audio callback?

Tags: multithreading, audio, real-time, core-audio, multicore

First, some relevant background info:  I've got a CoreAudio-based low-latency audio processing application that does various mixing and special effects on audio that is coming from an input device on a purpose-dedicated Mac (running the latest version of MacOS) and delivers the results back to one of the Mac's local audio devices.

In order to obtain the best/most reliable low-latency performance, this app is designed to hook in to CoreAudio's low-level audio-rendering callback (via [AudioDeviceCreateIOProcID()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio/1423215-audiodevicecreateioprocid?language=objc), AudioDeviceStart(), etc) and every time the callback-function is called (from the CoreAudio's realtime context), it reads the incoming audio frames (e.g. 128 frames, 64 samples per frame), does the necessary math, and writes out the outgoing samples.

This all works quite well, but from everything I've read, Apple's CoreAudio implementation has an unwritten de-facto requirement that all real-time audio operations happen in a single thread.  There are good reasons for this which I acknowledge (mainly that outside of SIMD/SSE/AVX instructions, which I already use, almost all of the mechanisms you might employ to co-ordinate parallelized behavior are not real-time-safe and therefore trying to use them would result in intermittently glitchy audio).

However, my co-workers and I are greedy, and nevertheless we'd like to do many more math-operations per sample-buffer than even the fastest single core could reliably execute in the brief time-window that is necessary to avoid audio-underruns and glitching.

My co-worker (who is fairly experienced at real-time audio processing on embedded/purpose-built Linux hardware) tells me that under Linux it is possible for a program to requisition exclusive access for one or more CPU cores, such that the OS will never try to use them for anything else.  Once he has done this, he can run "bare metal" style code on that CPU that simply busy-waits/polls on an atomic variable until the "real" audio thread updates it to let the dedicated core know it's time to do its thing; at that point the dedicated core will run its math routines on the input samples and generate its output in a (hopefully) finite amount of time, at which point the "real" audio thread can gather the results (more busy-waiting/polling here) and incorporate them back into the outgoing audio buffer.

My question is, is this approach worth attempting under MacOS/X?  (i.e. can a MacOS/X program, even one with root access, convince MacOS to give it exclusive access to some cores, and if so, will big ugly busy-waiting/polling loops on those cores (including the polling-loops necessary to synchronize the CoreAudio callback-thread relative to their input/output requirements) yield results that are reliably real-time enough that you might someday want to use them in front of a paying audience?)

It seems like something that might be possible in principle, but before I spend too much time banging my head against whatever walls might exist there, I'd like some input about whether this is an avenue worth pursuing on this platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can a MacOS/X program, even one with root access, convince MacOS to give it exclusive access to some cores

I don't know about that, but you can use as many cores / [real-time threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html) as you want for your calculations, using whatever synchronisation methods you need to make it work, then pass the audio to your `IOProc` using a lock free ring buffer, like [TPCircularBuffer](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer).

But your question reminded me of a new macOS 11/iOS 14 API I've been meaning to try, [the Audio Workgroups API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/workgroup_management/understanding_audio_workgroups) ([2020 WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10224/)).

My understanding is that this API lets you "bless" your non-IOProc [real-time threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html) with audio real-time thread properties or at least cooperate better with the audio thread.

The documents distinguish between the threads [working in parallel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/workgroup_management/adding_parallel_real-time_threads_to_audio_workgroups) (this sounds like your case) and [working asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/workgroup_management/adding_asynchronous_real-time_threads_to_audio_workgroups) (this sounds like my  proposal), I don't know which case is better for you.

I still don't know what happens in practice when you use `Audio Workgroups`, whether they opt you in to good stuff or opt you out of bad stuff, but if they're not the hammer you're seeking, they may have some useful hammer-like properties.